# Jquery sum of two multiplyed field

Tags: jquery, devise, sum

i created a Multi-input exchange rate, i want to calculate the sum of multiple input textfield * select option devise 
i found the solution but the problem when i put 0 he read like a 1 :

[image]
[image]

```
 $('input.summable,.multiply').keyup(function() {
     var rate = 0;
     var box  = 0;
        rate +=   $('input.summable').val();
        box +=  $('.multiply').val();
       var sum = (rate *box);
      $('input.summable,.multiply').each(function() { sum += parseFloat(this.value); });
      $('#totalsum').val(sum);
    });
```

Comment: can you add your relevant HTML code here?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to calculate and what the result should be? I found your way a bit strange. You first do `var sum = (rate * box);` and than `sum += ...` in your `each`. So `1 * 2 = 2 = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is based on:

- use input instead of keyup for text field
- in order to convert a string to a number prefix the string with a plus sign like: +"00"

My example:

```js
$('input.summable,.multiply').on('input change', function (e) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input.summable').each(function(i, e) {
    sum += (+this.value * +$('.multiply').eq(i).val());
  });
  $('#totalsum').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    Montant: <input class="summable form-text" type="text" name="name" value size="60" maxlength="128"><br>
    Device:     <select class="multiply form-select" name="money">
    <option value="5.91">BHD</option>
    <option value="1.712">CAD</option>
    <option value="33.245">DKK</option>
</select>
    <br>
    Montant: <input class="summable form-text" type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value size="60" maxlength="128"><br>
    Device:     <select class="multiply form-select" name="money">
    <option value="5.91">BHD</option>
    <option value="1.712">CAD</option>
    <option value="33.245">DKK</option>
</select>
    <br>
    En Dinnar: <input id="totalsum" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: i want to be dynamically and for each input

Comment: its work but you have the same probleme ! why when i put : 0 it give me a value??

Comment: @Salaktarus Answer updated, could you take a look and let me know? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to multiply field `.summable` with `.multiply`, you dont need the `each` loop.
2. A `select` don't has `keyup` event, you need `change` event here.

```js
// add change event too
$('.summable, .multiply').on("keyup change", function() {
    var rate = parseFloat($('.summable').val());
    var box  = parseFloat($('.multiply').val());
    var sum  = rate * box;
  
    // remove this
    // $('.summable, .multiply').each(function() {
    //     sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    // });
  
    $('#totalsum').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

sum:
<input class="summable" type="text">
<br />

multi:
<select class="multiply">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<br />

total:
<input id="totalsum" type="text">
```